# Interactive Plots in Python

Tags: python, plot, interactive

How to plot interactive plots in python, I am on dataframe which is datetime indexed, I want to plot multiple columns by selecting from the wizard, on the time axis, there should be some function to behave like a date slider as well so that selecting a range in the plot can change the date.
Any suggestion?

I have no idea about the interactive plots, being new to python I can just plot pd or matplotlib plot as basic